# Search a part of string of datatype Mediumtext/Largetext

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I am working on mysql workbench and I want to search a part of string through entire database. The problem is, there are around 550 tables and I don't know which table and column has that data. I have a script that searches almost any datatype but is ineffective to mediumtext and longtext. I know these are different datatypes and conventional searches techniques such as 'like', '=', 'in', 'between' would not be used.

`SET @column_types_regexp = '^((var)?char|(var) binary|blob|text|longtext|mediumtext|enum|set)\\(';`

The above script is from
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34856/how-to-search-whole-mysql-database-for-a-particular-string
*(note I have added longtext and mediumtext by my side)*
If anyone could show me searching through mediumtext or longtext, that would be of great help. Thanks for your time.

Comment: "there are around 550 tables and I don't know which table and column has that data. I have a script that searches almost any datatype but is ineffective to mediumtext and longtext. " it almost makes more sense to do a binary search on the MySQL's server file system's directory..

Comment: "I know these are different datatypes and conventional searches techniques such as 'like', '=', 'in', 'between' would not be used. " You should change the function that the SQL uses `MATCH (col1,col2,...) AGAINST (expr [search_modifier])` ( https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html ) instead when the column type is a text variant..